# Docker build failed: lstat /root/go: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, go, makefile, swagger, go-swagger

I am dockerizing my app that runs in a custom base image with alpine:golang and goswagger installed. Currently, I'm trying to reduce the image size by implementing a multistage build. But when I run

`swagger generate`

it always showing error message:

`lstat /root/go: no such file or directory`

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it? Ive checked in `root/go` directory and it is valid no `go` folder there but I can confirm the installation of go with running go build.

Here is my dockerfile

```
# Custom image with alpine and go:1.18.2 + goswagger installed

# Build binary stage
FROM gcrdomain/mycomp/go:1.18.2 as build

WORKDIR /app

# Install make
RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc libc-dev

COPY . .

# swagger validate + clean + generate
RUN make all

# Serve the binary stage

# Bare image with required deps to serve static binary
FROM scratch

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/telemedicine-proxy-server /telemedicine-proxy-server

CMD ["/telemedicine-proxy-server", "--port=8080", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: Looks like problem with go binary, try add to you `swagger generate` target `go env` output.

Comment: `go-swagger`  is afaik codegen. It probably depends on some files inside its source tree installed to `GOPATH` (assuming `/root/go` is default one for user root). Does your `make all` call `go install` to get go-swagger installed?

Comment: The Dockerfile you included doesn't have a `swagger generate` call or any reference to a `/root` directory.  Can you [edit] the question to include the relevant fragment(s) of your Makefile as well?

Comment: Actually the base image that i used is custom image with swagger installed on it, *i forgot to add that

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the issue, I've checked our custom base image and figured out that in our base image dockerfile the `GOPATH` is not placed in `/root`

```
ENV GO_PATH=/go
```

I've changed it to

```
ENV GO_PATH=/root/go
```

and everything worked as expected, thanks for all the comments!:D